.NET 8.0 Not Normalizing Whitespace for xs:token Elements?
I'm working with C# and .NET 8.0.6.
I have an XSD that declares a "root" element with xs:token content.  When I validate a document with an instance element that has padded content, the padding is preserved?  I'm expecting the padding (leading and trailing whitespace) to be removed.
The XSD is:
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<xs:schema
    targetNamespace = "http://example.org/scratch"
    xmlns           = "http://example.org/scratch"
    xmlns:xs        = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="root" type="xs:token"/>

</xs:schema>

The instance is:
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<pre:root xmlns:pre="http://example.org/scratch">   abc   </pre:root>


My code that does the following:

Reads the XSD as a System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.
Adds the schema to a System.Xml.Schema.SchemaSet which is then compiled.
Creates an XmlReader (XsdValidatingReader) using:

    var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        CheckCharacters = true,
        DtdProcessing   = DtdProcessing.Prohibit,
        Schemas         = xmlSchemaSet,
        ValidationType  = ValidationType.Schema,
    };


Loads the instance using System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(xmlReader).


The document object yields:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pre:root xmlns:pre="http://example.org/scratch">   abc   </pre:root>

In particular, the XmlDocument.DocumentElement has:

InnerXml:                       "   abc   "
NamespaceURI:                   "http://example.org/scratch"
SchemaInfo.SchemaType.TypeCode: "Token"


What is the question? Check it out here: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xml-schema/0596002521/re95.html

I am not sure in the .NET DOM (i.e. System.Xml.XmlDocument/XmlNode/XmlElement) you will find schema typed values. Use the XPathNavigator/XPathDocument https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.typedvalue?view=net-8.0. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/accessing-strongly-typed-xml-data-using-xpathnavigator

XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace would be a good start, but that's significant whitespace because the text is not only whitespace.

@YitzhakKhabinsky — See the second paragraph. I don't understand why the leading and trailing spaces have not been removed from the content of an element typed as xs:token.

@Charlieface — XmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace controls ignoring insignificant whitespace.  However, whitespace in element content is significant.

@MartinHonnen — I'm guessing it does since, as seen at the end of the question, the SchemaInfo.SchemaType.TypeCode: "Token" is correct for XmlDocument.DocumentElement.  Also, I'm just learning XML, so I can't experiment with XPath just yet.

If you want someone to fully interrogate your code's logic, you should post a [mre].

The padding isn't removed because XML Schema validation doesn't modify an instance document's content.
I wrongly assumed that any whitespace normalization applied to an xs:token is persisted.  However, no such modifications are prescribed in the XSD specification. Any normalization is internal to the validation process.
Although instance content isn't modified during validation, it can be augmented.  Adding default values is one example.  Adding information to the post schema validation infoset (PSVI) is another.
Per .NET and C#, an XML node's PSVI information can be accessed via XmlNode.SchemaInfo and used to perform a post-validation transformation.  For example, given a SchemaInfo.SchemaType.TypeCode of XmlTypeCode.Token, an application could normalize the content's whitespace.

I still think https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.typedvalue?view=net-8.0 should give you abc and not    abc   , but it seems it indeed just returns the unnormalized string. I rather consider it a bug in that API that the xs:token value is not returned normalized.

@MartinHonnen Consider posting this to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions.

I tried my luck to raise it as a potential issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/104507

You are facing peculiar nuances of the XSD validation.
First, it is applying xs:token data type to the element value, collapsing whitespaces, and just after that it is running its validation.
If you need to enforce whitespaces presence as invalid, try the following XSD.
XSD
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.org/scratch"
           xmlns="http://example.org/scratch"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[^\s]+"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>


You seem to imply that whitespace replacement is performed for validation but that the results are not persisted in the post validation DOM?  However, .NET (e.g.) augments validated instances with default values for missing elements.  Also, the link you provided above (oreilly) states that the value space of an xs:token element is the string "after whitespace replacement".  (See the example.)  So, I'm expecting to see the whitepsace replaced, but suspect I'm doing something wrong.

You need to speak in terms of validation results: valid or invalid.

@voidp Validation doesn't modify the XML, it just checks it's OK. The spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#token says that restrictions on a xs:token (for example min/max length etc) apply only after collapsing, but this has nothing to do with actually modifying the XML, it's all about validation. If the XML is validated then a conformant XSD deserializer will then parse out the trimmed value. See eg https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tt1VDR where you can verify that the string is being trimmed. Put it this way: the XML itself doesn't change, it's what you parse out of it that does.

@Charlieface Agreed.  I got tripped up by infoset augmentation.  When I saw that default values were being added, I wrongly expected content to be transformed corresponding to schema type.

Using SaxonCS (requires a commercial license) you can use a schema-aware document builder to parse the XML input into an XDM document and then you can get the typed value:
using Saxon.Api;

using Path = System.IO.Path;

using static Saxon.Api.Steps;

var processor = new Processor();

processor.SchemaManager.Compile(new Uri(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "schema1.xsd")));

var schemaValidator = processor.SchemaManager.NewSchemaValidator();

var docBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();

docBuilder.SchemaValidator = schemaValidator;

var xdmNode = docBuilder.Build(new Uri(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "sample1.xml")));

foreach (var item in xdmNode.OutermostElement.Select(Child("item")))
{
    foreach (var child in item.Children())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Child {child.NodeName}: typed value: |{child.TypedValue}|");
    }
}

Example XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <item>
    <string>   abc   </string>
    <token>   abc   </token>
    <date>   2024-07-01   </date>
    <tokens>   foo   bar   baz </tokens>
  </item>
  <item>
    <string>   abc   </string>
    <token>   abc   </token>
    <date>   2024-07-01   </date>
    <tokens>   foo   bar   baz </tokens>
  </item>
</root> 

Example schema:
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="item">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="token" type="xs:token"/>
              <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
              <xs:element name="tokens" type="xs:NMTOKENS"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Example program output:
Child string: typed value: |   abc   |
Child token: typed value: |abc|
Child date: typed value: |2024-07-01|
Child tokens: typed value: |"foo"
"bar"
"baz"|
Child string: typed value: |   abc   |
Child token: typed value: |abc|
Child date: typed value: |2024-07-01|
Child tokens: typed value: |"foo"
"bar"
"baz"|

